# Jetpack Compose - Unexpected vertical padding on Card

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun OutcomeItem(outcome: Outcome, onVote: () -> Unit) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        elevation = 4.dp,
        onClick = { onVote() }
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(4.dp)
            ,
            text = outcome.title,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
        )
    }
}
```

▲ Composable with unexpected vertical padding

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun OutcomeItemPreview() {
    SuperBowlTheme {
        OutcomeItem(outcome = Outcome("4반 승!", arrayListOf())) {}
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBa13.png
I couldn't post inline image, sorry

▲My preview

I have no idea where did that vertical padding came from.
I've tried adding .padding(0.dp) on Card modifier, but it didn't work

++ root composable of OutcomeItem

```
@Composable
fun OutcomeContent(outcomes: List<Outcome>) {
    if (outcomes.size <= 2) {
        TwoOutcomeContent(outcomes)
    } else
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            outcomes.forEach { outcome ->
                OutcomeItem(outcome = outcome) {  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have u checked it on a real device ? Also do you have a root Composable where you add this one ?

Comment: Tried on a real device and could not replicate the issue, so as suggested above, the problem might be with the root composable.

Comment: remove the ``wrapContentHeight`` because cardView wrapping the content according to its height. that's why it creates this padding.

Comment: Tried removing the wrapContentHeight, still same... I've added root composable in post btw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Card specifies a minimum size defined by the minimum touch target size; your content doesn't fill that space, so the padding is added outside of the card.

You can either make the content taller, or wrap your card and tell it to not enforce the minimum touch target size.

I wouldn't recommend it, but this is how you'd ignore the minimum size:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun OutcomeItem(outcome: Outcome, onVote: () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false,
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            elevation = 4.dp,
            onClick = { onVote() }
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp),
                text = outcome.title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
        }
    }
}
```